# Spring: Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Been working in developing microservices with Spring. I've written several, succesfully, however, this last one is failling and I don't know why.

```
Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

My application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Sat
spring.datasource.username=user_auto
spring.datasource.password=
```

(Don't worry, the password is included in the application.properties)

Already trying added and removing:

spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.8</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sat.serviciodescargamasiva.automatizador</groupId>
    <artifactId>automatizador</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>automatizador</name>
    <description>Servicio de automatizador del SAT</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud-gcp.version>3.2.1</spring-cloud-gcp.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-storage</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-gcp.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.yml</include>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My main:

@SpringBootApplication
public class AutoApplication {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AutoApplication.class, args);
}
```

}

I'm writing my code in IntelliJ. Help, I don't know what to do! I think I've ran out of possible solutions.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same problem. I also tried different solutions given in the answers, but nothing worked for me. I finally found out that the problem is with the pom.xml (if your dependency manager is maven). I had the following block there & after removing it the problem was resolved.

```
   <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>/src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>../src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

The problem was that spring auto-configuration could not detect the correct resource folder. Removing this will make no harm to your program.

Answer (score 1):

For some odd reason i had an empty `application.properties` file at `target\classes` folder. I just deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this dependency :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I'm not sure if it can be combined with mysql driver:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

You can also try changing this one:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name -> spring.datasource.driverClassName
```

Or, according to [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-failed-to-configure-data-source) change it to :

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: Tried both, no result :(

Comment: Maybe try to change/remove the scope of mysql driver dependency  from runtime to provided or something else <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>  
        </dependency>

Comment: Still not solved @a_glampedakis

Answer (score -1):

Check your pom.xml file and make sure its packaging is **war**. It worked for me :)

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Comment: don't write foolish answers